# Spring Boot Kafka @SendTo can't read kafka_replyTopic header

Tags: java, spring-boot, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I'm using @SendTo annotation with no args on a consumer receiver in spring boot application. The received message contains header "Kafka_replyTopic", but the @SendTo cannot read it and kafka throws an exception on sending the reply:

```
Listener failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: With no topic header, a defaultTopic is required
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by setting the spring-boot-starter-parent version in the consumer application the same as that in the producer application (v. 2.3.2.RELEASE)

I don't know if the problem was with the old version itself (v. 2.2.6.RELEASE) in the consumer application or was that its version was different from that of the producer application.

Comment: I assume you are returning a `Message<?>` - this was [indeed a change](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#reply-message) in spring-kafka 2.5 (pulled in by boot 2.3). It's generally best to show the listener method signature when asking questions like this.

Comment: Yes I'm using Message<?>